# Can I customize the csv double quote escape character for auto-formatting and syntax checker?

Tags: emeditor

I have a csv file I'm having to generate for a third party.  They require that double quotes in a quoted column be escaped with a backslash instead of the standard double-quote.  Of course, EmEditor's auto-formatting doesn't work on those lines and it always thinks my file is invalid.

```
1,"DINNER PLATE 6.25\"",1234
```

Is there any way to configure EmEditor to treat the backslash as an escape character?

Please note, the requirements are from a third party and cannot be changed and the quotes are absolutely necessary and cannot be stripped to avoid having to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a full solution, but have you considered replacing the required double quotes in a quoted column with the "closing double quote": ”

That way Emeditor should work as expected and once you have created/manipulated the file, as a last step, you can do a global replace:

Find:”  (or \” if you choose to replace with that)

Replace: \" (standard escaped double quote)

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor supports a backslash to escape a quotation mark. Please make sure you use a latest version of EmEditor, and set the `Use escape character` option in the `CSV Formats` page of the `Customize` dialog box while your choice of a CSV format is selected.

Comment: I did find the option you mentioned, thank you for that.  But it will not work for me because EmEditor is not allowing me to have delimiters in quotes AND an escape character like the third party requires.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: You don't need to set both options. Clear the `Allow delimiters in quotes` option, and set the `Use escape character` option. What is the issue with this setting?